# Open With is Grey in File Info

Tags: defaults

How to change the default application that is used to open a file when its icon is double clicked in Finder?

This is in macOS 13.1. If I right click on the file and select "Get Info", the configurations in the "Open with:" section is grey and cannot be changed. This is where in earlier versions of macOS the default application was set. Is there a new place where this is to be changed or is there some step or condition that I'm missing? There is a gold lock in the lower right corner of the Info window. I have unlocked that icon and the settings are still grey. I can see that the user I am logged in as has Read and Write privilege for this file, and I just created this file a moment ago to begin with. The file type is `.url` and the content in the file is

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://example.com/
```

[image]

Comment: Does your user account have Admin rights?

Comment: No. This is a normal user. That's a good observation. I will check if this behavior is the same when logged in as the admin. Is there a way to make this change to default app on the command line? I'd like to be able to do this within the login if this is the problem.

Comment: I'll have to research if it's possible on the command line.  I haven't been in the "work" environment for a couple of years (sorta retired) and I do everything as an admin so I don't run into stuff like that as often.